# ASP.NET2.0 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()

Tags: forms-authentication, asp.net-2.0

NET 2.0 form authentication.

Also i am using Login Web server control in aspx page.

My question is that , Is it necessary to write FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() method when we are using "Login Web server control " because i think it automatically create authentication cookie when we are using login control.

I don't know i am right or not, please make me clear?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything if you are using the login server control.